# Ant Dynamic parmeter name

Tags: dynamic, ant, parameters

i have tried to find an answer reading some ant-contib posts but couldn't get a good one.
on my ant build.xml file i have a dynamic paramter name which changes each build.
the parameter name includes version of components for example :

```
<componentX>.<ComponentVersion>=y
```

how can i access the value of this parameter in my build.xml file  ?

i have tried to read the parameter using this :

${componentX.${ComponentVersion}} but it does not work.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is normal ant properties & is set to some value & if you want to get values of concatenated result, then below way would work:

```
<property name="componentX" value="foo"/>
<property name="ComponentVersion" value="bar"/>
```

Then outputting like below :

```
<echo message="${componentX}.${ComponentVersion}"/> <!-- would print foo.bar -->
```

OR storing in new `property` like for later use:

```
<property name="concat.one" value="${componentX}.${ComponentVersion}"/>
```